# react redux asyc tasks with rest api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

In my new project register user must pass 3 step

1. User enter phone number
2. verify phone number with sms code
3. complete personal info

user register work with rest api
the first api post the phone number and return 4 digit code and the code store in redux
then user must insert 4 digit if it correct second api post phone number and digit, if user phone number not register before return a empty string else return a token and store in redux
when i get the response i want to check if it's a empty string user go to step 3 else show a error message now i do this whit setTimeout but it's not a right way and im lokking for right way

this is my code:

```
// check user insert correct 4 digit
if (this.state.smsCode === this.props.smsCode) {

      // Post phone number and sms code with redux action
      this.props.setUserToken(this.state.phoneNumber, this.state.smsCode);

      setTimeout(() => {

        if (this.props.userToken === "") {
          // go to next step
        } else {
          // show error
        }
      }, 4000);
    }
```

Comment: Use componentDidUpdate lifecycle method (or useEffect hook)

Comment: @TiagoCoelho can you give a example code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick comment then an example implementation**

**JS Best Practice**

Using a setTimeout like that is a terrible JS practice. It's something indicative of not having your imagination around how an async/multithreaded language does work and should be implemented. If the server is throttled and takes 5000ms to return a response, you'll miss it. Conversely, if it takes 10ms, your user will be waiting 3990ms for no reason. setUserToken should either accept a callback as an argument or return a promise, allowing for async code execution. i.e.

```
this.props.setUserToken(this.state.phoneNumber, this.state.smsCode)
.then(res => {/*move on*/})
.catch(err => {/*display error*/})

// OR

this.props.setUserToken(
  this.state.phoneNumber, 
  this.state.smsCode, 
  (res, err) => {
    if(err) {
      // set error
    } else {
      // move on
    }
)
```

**Example**

Below you can see an implementation that would work for the requirements you laid out. It has three views it will render, a phone number input form, code submission form, and a validated view form. Hook your server calls into this and it'll work:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      step: 'phone',
      number: null,
      error: undefined
    }

    this.requestCode = phoneNumber => {
        // api request code here with phone number
        /*
        api.requestCode(phoneNumber, (res, err) => console.log(err ? 'FAIL' : 'WE DID IT!'))
        */
    }

    this.verifyCode = code => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // api request here submitting the code asynchronously
        // in the async function triggered when the api responds, 
        // either set an error or allow them through:
        /*
        api.verifyCode(code, (res, err) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(res)
            }

        })
        */
    })

    this.submitPhoneNumber = e => {
      const phoneNumber = this.refs.phoneInput.value

      this.setState({
        step: 'code',
        number: phoneNumber
      })

      this.requestCode(phoneNumber)
    }

    this.submitCode = e => {
        const code = this.refs.codeInput.value
        this.verifyCode(code)
            .then(res => this.setState({step: 'authenticated'}))
            .catch(err => this.setState({error: err}))
    }
  }

  renderInputPhone() {
    return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.submitPhoneNumber}>
        <div>Input phone number</div>
        <input ref="phoneInput"></input>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">submit!</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onClick={e => this.requestCode(this.state.number)}>Resent code</button>
        </div>

      </form>
      <div>
        <button onClick={e => this.setState({step: 'phone'})}>back</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    )
  }

  renderCodeInput() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submitCode}>
        <div>Input sent code</div>
        <input ref="codeInput" defaultValue={this.state.number}></input>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">submit!</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }

  renderAutheticatedView() {
    return (
        <div>we're in</div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.step === 'phone' ? this.renderInputPhone()
      : this.state.step === 'code' ? this.renderCodeInput()
      : this.state.step === 'authenticated' ? this.renderAutheticatedView()
      : null
    );
  }
}
```